# Formal logic proof of absolute value formula

Tags: logic

I've been trying to prove this for a long time now, anyone willing to offer some help or get me pointed in the right direction?

$(x>0 \implies z = x) \wedge (x < 0 \implies z = -x) \implies z \ge 0$

Comment: Re-tagged as "logic" instead of "higher-order-logic", as this is  first-order logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: What happens if x = 0?  Does that say anything about z?

Answer (score 3):

As Robert's answer indicates, the statement is false.  However, changing the first $>$ to $\geq$ gives a true statement which I would use a proof by contradiction, that is assume $z < 0$ and $(x \geq 0 \implies z = x) \wedge (x < 0 \implies z = -x)$ and derive a contradiction. This can be done as follows:

$(z < 0) \wedge ((x>0 \implies z = x) \wedge (x < 0 \implies z = -x))$
$\implies (((x \geq 0 \implies z = x) \wedge z < 0) \wedge ((x < 0 \implies z = -x) \wedge z < 0))$
$\implies ((x \geq 0 \implies x < 0) \wedge (x < 0 \implies -x < 0))$
$\implies ((F \wedge (x < 0 \implies -x < 0)) \vee ((x \geq 0 \implies x < 0) \wedge F))$
$\implies (F \vee F)$
$\implies F$
$\therefore \neg((z < 0) \wedge ((x \geq 0 \implies z = x) \wedge (x < 0 \implies z = -x)))$
$\therefore (x \geq 0 \implies z = x) \wedge (x < 0 \implies z = -x) \implies z \ge 0$

Comment: As @Robert's answer indicates, the statement is actually false, since $x$ need not be either $<0$ or $>0$; it could be $0$ (if it's implicitly assumed to be a real number; else it could also be $2+3\mathrm{i}$ or something else entirely). It follows that this proof must be flawed. The error is in replacing $(x>0\implies x<0)$ by $F$, since this implication is actually true if $x>0$ is false.

Comment: @Joriki: Thanks, I missed that. Fixed.